Mapping property names between DTO and entity for sorting in a Spring Pageable object
Description
Given a Spring Boot REST controller with a GET method:

Accepting a Pageable object for sorting the reults.
Returning a UserResponse object with property names different from that of the UserEntity.

Here is some basic code for illustration:
// User controller

public class UserController {

    UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<UserResponse> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {
        return userRepository.findAll(pageable).stream().map(UserMapper::toUserResponse);
    }
}

// User response

public class UserResponse {

    String userName;
}

// User entity

@Entity
public class UserEntity {

    String name;
}

Problem
A client would like to sort the results by the property name userName as defined in the UserResponse. As the corresponding field in the UserEntity is called name, the sorting does not work and results in an exception.
Questions

Is it possible to perform some kind of mapping between the property names for sorting?
I already use MapStruct which maps between the UserEntity and the UserResponse objects. Would it be possible to re-use this for the mapping of sort property names?


You can use dynamic proxy:
Pageable proxyPageable = (Pageable) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                new Class[] { Pageable.class },
                (proxy, method, methodArgs) -> {
                    if (method.getName().equals("getSort")) {
                        return Sort.by(
                        pageable.getSort().stream().map(order -> {
                            if (order.getProperty().equals("userName")) {
                                return new Sort.Order(order.getDirection(), "name");
                            }
                            return order;
                        }).toList());
                    } else {
                        return method.invoke(pageable, methodArgs);
                    }
                });



try this, inside your UserMapper class :
@Mapping(source = "name", target = "userName")
UserResponse toUserResponse(UserEntity userEntity);


My question is about a name mapping between the Sort and entity properties. Thus, your answer unfortunately does not solve my problem.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Just change change pageable to your own
final Pageable of = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by(pageable.getSort()
                .map(order -> order.getProperty().equals("name") ? new Order(order.getDirection(), "userName") : order)
                .toList()));
return userRepository.findAll(of).map(UserMapper::toUserResponse);

